# Groovy: Check if text contains a string more than one time

Tags: java, groovy

I want to check if the word `"test"` appears more than 1 time in the logs.
The following code just checks if the word `'test'` appears more than 0 times in the string. (it just checks if the logs contain the word).

```
 if (env.logs.contains('test')) {
      xxx
}
```

What do I have to change to let this part of code check for more than one appearances of the word `test`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `contains()` method simply does this:

```
public boolean contains(CharSequence s) {
    return indexOf(s.toString()) > -1;
}
```

Therefore you can do this to check if the value appears more than once:

```
int index = env.logs.indexOf("test");
if ((index > -1) && (env.logs.indexOf("test", index + 1) > -1) ) {
        // do something here
}
```

Comment: As a bonus question: how did you peek inside it?

Answer (score 3):

Using matcher:

```
def match = (env.logs =~ /test/)
assert match.size() > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try:

```
if (env.logs.count('test') > 2) {
...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Increment a value when if condition is true

like as

```
int testCount=0;
 if (env.logs.contains('test')) {
  testCount++;
 }
```

and check condtion

if testCount>0 then write somethinng what you want.

Comment: This does not work because for the `testCount` to increase this has to be called multiple times and the `contains` will always find the fist appearance of `test` ending in an endless loop if `contains` returns true.

Comment: The code in this answer will result in testCount being set to 1 if "test" is present in the logs string, regardless of the number of occurrences. It does not solve the author's question of counting/checking if this text exists more than once.